# Google app engine redirect based on http header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

In app engine app.yaml in the `handlers` section, I would like to specify a redirect based on http header.

so if a request comes with this header route it elsewhere.

is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the app.yaml mainly due to the reason that you are unable to detect specific custom headers only set them for your response as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element).

What you need to do for a situation like this is manage request headers through your app code to detect the headers you are looking for. Do keep in the header restrictions of using GAE as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers#request_headers) states:

> For security purposes, some headers are sanitized, amended, or removed
> by intermediate proxies before they reach the application.

Here is a quick example of how you could do so in python using flask

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    if request.headers['your-header-name']:
        return redirect(url_for('foo'))
    else:
        return 'Hello World'

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return 'Hello Foo!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```